How can I communicate my belief that someone has been "returned" rather than "died/passed away/lost"?
I believe that the body of a living thing is a vessel and the soul exits upon death.
I do not believe in a God, but do believe the Universe is unknowable by human beings and so I reserve judgment on what happens after death.  For me, saying any living being, much less one that I loved, "died" or "passed away" or "was lost" does not ring true to me.  I have read that some philosophers believe the soul is "returned" (to the earth/universe/unknown) and that idea resonates with me.  However, when I say it, people do not know what I am talking about.
I want to convey my true feeling, but wonder if anyone knows how to best convey this philosophy on death without offending or elaborating on my own beliefs.  Thank you.

Someone says that if you can't explain your theory to others, then you don't understand it yourself.
So when you try to explain your "returned" theory to others, have you really figured out what's going on?

This isn't a philosophy question, it's an interpersonal relationships question. If you're talking about your loss, use whatever language you want. If you are taking to someone else about their loss, keep it as basic as possible while not violating your beliefs, and don't choose this moment to inflict the more complicated details of your belief(s) on them.

Well... First, let’s dispense with the niceties: people get very touchy about death. It’s one of the few universal experiences we all share but are woefully ill-equipped to discuss. Most people cling to familiar terms because they offer a comforting script in the face of the unknown. So, when you introduce a new term like "returned," it’s little wonder that it raises eyebrows. However, if you wish to convey your belief without offending or launching into a metaphysical lecture, you’ll need to do a bit of linguistic sleight of hand. Here’s a suggestion: context is your ally. Rather than dropping "returned" into conversation with no preamble, provide a brief framing.
For instance, you might say, "I believe that when someone dies, their essence is returned to the universe." This way, you’ve laid the groundwork for your terminology. It’s clear, concise, and doesn’t require an extended discourse on your metaphysical views. It’s a small bridge to understanding, rather than a leap into the abyss of the unknown.

Yes, speaking with people in terms they understand, and explaining your terms is the best advice.

The Simulation Theory could provide a good explanation.
But you need to accept some assumptions about the future:

Within the next 500-1000 years, humans will be able to upload consciousness into digital format and give people the potential for immortality.

In 300 years, humans will be able to build a simulated reality that very closely resembles our world.


Now, if you believe that the statements above could possibly be true, then you have to accept that there is a chance that your life is part of the Simulator where digitized consciousness obtains the virtual body for the duration of your life.

It's also possible within the next 100 years there will be no humans left ... nuclear winter? Global warming?? Maybe more prosaically we all will just drown in an avalanche of plastic???  Point being if ppl can say global warming is an unverified theory, surely simulation hypothesis is mote so?

@Rushi - Philosopher don't know anything. But Philosopher can think rationally. If you took pains to create a simulation, what is the point of destroying it?

You are pumping iron. 3rd set. Maximum weight. Face flushed. Panting. Pushing at maximum capacity. This is your side. At the side of your tissues whats the story? Pandemonium. And at the cells? Death! Not just in muscles but even in bones. Likewise the human genome is effectively infinitely more longlived than an individual human, And the cosmos effectively infinitely more than the human species. I strongly suspect we are an experiment that will soon be sidelined and bypassed. There is nonzero evidence of species failed

@Rushi - there is a more interesting question: if you are an immortal digital entity, why would you be interested in entering a mortal body?

For us it is the ultimate calamity. For the cosmos its just some wasted "lab equipment"

In a good simulator, nothing is wasted. For each run, for each failure or success, information is preserved.

It is hard (for me) to imagine unqualified immortality. Is the earth immortal? Sun? Galaxy?  For me immortality always entails an assumed stable frame. G.I. Gurdjieff (who comes closest to the simulation hypothesis among spiritual masters) described 'spiritual greats like Buddha and Christ as "Immortal within the limits of the solar system"

A Thousand years - would mean practical immortality from our vantage point.
